# Yaml: default value for a variable

Tags: php, symfony, yaml

Here is my use case: we use Yaml to have hold all our environment configuration.
We have a `conguration.yml` that holds configuration for every environment and a `parameters.yml` that holds specific local configuration.

*parameters.yml*

```
value1:  abc
value2:  ~
```

*configuration.yml*

```
service:
    arg1: %value1%
    arg2: %value2%
```

---

**My question:** is there a way I can drop the `value2: ~` line without having a parsing error from Yaml? A kind of default value that we could define in *configuration.yml* in case `value2` is not defined?

Comment: I know little about YAML, but this question seems to suggest if you leave it out, it will be intepreted as null: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6745051/play-framework-how-can-i-make-play-accept-null-values-in-yaml-files

Comment: Why do you need to remove value2?

Comment: @SenseException otherwise a param not found error is thrown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can only specify a default value in the `parameters.yml.dist` files. This features is available only from symfony 2.3 and need a `composer install` for ask/update the configuration.

See the [features annuncement](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-3-interactive-management-of-the-parameters-yml-file) for further reading

Comment: `composer install` does not seem to modify `parameters.yml` on my side. I found this https://github.com/Incenteev/ParameterHandler that does the job, but are you sure symfony can handle this natively?

Comment: Yes, a post-hook of `composer install` process run the ParameterHandler component that manage only the "ignored parameters", so if you don't specify a key in the `parameters.yml`, it will put the key into reading it from the `parameters.yml.dist`

Comment: Hi @Maz please consider to upvote my answer if you find it useful

Answer (score 0):

I believe, it's possible in 2020 and later.

For example,
`arguments: ["@=container.hasParameter('some_param') ? parameter('some_param') : 'default_value'"]`

See also:

- https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/expression_language.html
  [Symfony2 conditional service declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25216089/symfony2-conditional-service-declaration)
- [Symfony2 conditional service declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25216089/symfony2-conditional-service-declaration)